# Batch to return line if a dynamic string is repeated

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find

Trying to figure out a way to have batch return a line from a log file if a string is repeated.  The string contains a time stamp, so the string changes.

I made an example log.
I wish to identify both lines when time stamped string repeats within the same second so I can record the Event# and time stamp from both lines   :

```
\\10.xx.xx.x0\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 07:48:25 Event: UNIQUE EVENT# 12456
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 07:48:25 File Read Begin: UNIQUE EVENT# 12456
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 07:48:25 WinRead Read: UNIQUE EVENT# 12456
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:20 Event: UNIQUE EVENT# 2467
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:20 File Read Begin: UNIQUE EVENT# 2467
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:**2017-12-15 12:34:20 WinRead Read**: UNIQUE EVENT# 2467
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:20 Event: UNIQUE EVENT# 3214
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:20 File Read Begin: UNIQUE EVENT# 3214
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:**2017-12-15 12:34:20 WinRead Read**: UNIQUE EVENT# 3214
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:26 Event: UNIQUE EVENT# 6251
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:26 File Read Begin: UNIQUE EVENT# 6251
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-15 12:34:26 WinRead Read: UNIQUE EVENT# 6251
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-16 04:35:29 Event: UNIQUE EVENT# 1547
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-16 04:35:29 File Read Begin: UNIQUE EVENT# 1547
\\10.xx.xx.x0\\c$\PATH\file.log:2017-12-16 04:35:29 WinRead Read: UNIQUE EVENT# 1547
```

This is as far as I can get before I get hung up

```
findstr /r ....\-..\-.....\:..\:...Event.* file.log > temp.txt
    FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('temp.txt') do (FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO set STR1=%%g)
```

Comment: If you haven't tried anything then your question is off topic because this site is dedicated to helping you fix your own code, not writing it for you.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying into the question. If you do not have any code and need to hire a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Comment: Have you entered `FindStr /?` at the command propmt for help on that command? I'm sure that there's a basic regular expression reference within it which may help explain what may be wrong in your first line.

Comment: I fixed the findstr so it reduces the events to a single line and places them into another file.  I cant figure out how to show the lines that contain a duplicate or repeated date / time stamp  string .

Comment: There are six (6) lines timestamped `2017-12-15 12:34:20`. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @lit  The output would be all lines containing  2017-12-15 12:34:20

Comment: The timestamps in the example would fall into groups of 3, 6, 3, and 3. Which records would be omitted. What is the goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q48264584.txt"
SET "lastevent="

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"^|findstr /i "winread" ') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=W#" %%d IN ("%%b") DO (
  IF "!lastevent!"=="%%d" (
   ECHO !lastevent! #!lastunique!
   ECHO %%d #%%e
  )
  SET "lastevent=%%d"
  SET "lastunique=%%e"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q48264584.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Using what appears to be the required data, analysis reveals that the required lines uniquely contain the datestamp directly after the first `:` and the word `winread`, hence

Read each line of the file that contains `winread`. Tokenise using `:` so that the part before the first `:` goes to `%%a` (which is ignored) and the remainder of the line to `%%b`.

Then tokenise `%%b` using delimiters of `w` (which terminates the datestamp) and `#` (which precedes the required event number). Select tokens 1 (the datestamp) and 3 (the event number) to `%%d`,`%%e` respectively.

Using `delayed expansion`, compare the datestamp to `lastevent` and if the same then we have a repetition, so show the last event time and the last unique id (probably the names should be changed to `lastdatestamp` and `lastevent`) and their current values.

Regardless, save the data so that the next iteration compares against the values found in the previous (filtered) line.

---

In the light of the modification to the time format:

```
REM <!-- language: lang-dos -->
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q48264584.txt"
SET "lastevent="

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"^|findstr /i "winread" ') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=W#" %%d IN ("%%b") DO (
  CALL :comparetimes "%%d"
  IF DEFINED sametime (
   ECHO !lastevent! #!lastunique!
   ECHO %%d #%%e
  )
  SET "lastevent=%%d"
  SET "lastunique=%%e"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
::
:: Compare time in %1 to time in 'lastevent'
::
:comparetimes
SET "sametime="
IF NOT DEFINED lastevent GOTO :eof
SET "event2=%~1"
:: each of 'event2' and 'lastevent' are "date time" + space
:: select simply the time portion, except milliseconds
SET "event1=%lastevent:~-13,8%"
SET "event2=%event2:~-13,8%"
IF "%event1%"=="%event2%" SET "sametime=Y"&GOTO :EOF 
:: not same time - try difference 1 second - add 1 sec to event1
:: remove colons and string `1` before each time to convert to integer
:: 1000000 to 1235959; add 1 sec to event1
SET /a event2=1%event2::=%
SET /a event1=1%event1::=%+1
:: if last 2 digits of 'event1' are now "60" time was ??:??:59
:: so add 40 to bump minutes
IF 1%event1:~-2% geq 160 SET /a event1+=40
:: ditto hours...
IF 1%event1:~-4,2% geq 160 SET /a event1+=4000
:: finally days, but this time, event 1 MUST now be '1240000'+
:: so simply subtract 240000 
IF %event1% geq 1240000 SET /a event1-=240000

IF %event1% geq %event2% SET "sametime=Y"&GOTO :EOF 
GOTO :eof
```

All that's actually changed here is that `sametime` is a flag manipulated by the `:comparetimes` routine. `if defined` interprets the *run-time* value of the variable, so `delayedexpansion` is not required.

The `:comparetimes` routine accepts the date/time input from the main loop as its first parameter (%1) and assigns that to `event2` (since it's the second of the event-pair) as `%~1` which removes the enclosing quotes. We then select the `8` characters of the two times (`%1` and `lastevent`) starting at the `13`th character from the end - this will be hh:mm:ss.

If the two times are the same, we can set the `sametime` flag to report the data and we're done. Otherwise, the times are not the same, buy *may* differ by 1 second (...xx:999 to ...xx+1:000) so we need to deal with batch mathematics - which includes the cute idea that a number that begins with `0` is *octal* hence may not contain `8` or `9`. The normal way to do this is to string `1` before the string which makes it decimal, hence the odd adjustments that are required.

Note that for instance `12:59:59` will be converted to `1125959`. When we add 1 (second) to this, we get `1125960` so we need to add 100 and subtract 60 to make this `1126000`, then add 10000 and subtract 6000 to make it `1130000`.

I used `geq` instead of `equ/==` in order that the "window" of 1 second can be extended simply by changing the number added to `event1`. For instance, if this was 5 seconds, then `12:59:59` will be converted to `1125959`. When we add 5 (seconds) to this, we get `1125964` so we need to add 100 and subtract 60 to make this `1126004`, then add 10000 and subtract 6000 to make it `1130004` Hence, `event1` (now shifted 5 second forward) will be classed as "in the window" (of 5 seconds) if it is now `geq` (greater than or equal to) `event2`

Comment: Does this code handle the OP requirement to recognize `...repeats within the same second...`?

Comment: @lit: Since it must match the timestamp, then yes.

Comment: Ok. I thought the OP might have meant within one second such as 10:22:03 and 10:22:04. I guess not.

Comment: @lit: Could be. won't know until we get a response.

Comment: Attempted to test this but the logging I am parsing was enhanced to add milliseconds which complicated it ..  The time stamps were changed to this format 13:43:34:785 .  But the milliseconds are not relevant really. Still trying to identity lines where the date/time repeat to the same second on sequential lines .

Comment: @Magoo This Worked Thank you